# how to force all new links opening or redirects to stay inside the iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

when loading http://www.dmoz.org/ via iframe.

when you click on any of the links, it will escape out of the iframe.

how to disable this from happening ?

Comment: They're presumably breaking out of your frame for a reason. Respect the fact that they don't want you framing their content in that manner.

Comment: sorry that is not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, not really.  You can load their website in your frame because you control the link your visitor uses to enter that site from your page.  You do not control the dmoz site though and you have no control over how they set up their links.  If they have them set up in such a way that it breaks any frames, then your outta luck.

Comment: yes you can when you are loading them via proxy. i just dont know how to edit the javascripts to disable all iframe breakouts.